# CamelCase Jekyll Filter

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am trying to make a CamelCase Jekyll filter.

```
=begin
  # Custom to camelcase function
  # Usage:
  #   'string'.camelize
  #   'string'.camelize(:lower)
=end
class String
  def camelize(*separators)
    case separators.first
    when Symbol, TrueClass, FalseClass, NilClass
      first_letter = separators.shift
    end

    separators = ['_', '\s'] if separators.empty?

    str = self.dup

    separators.each do |s|
      str = str.gsub(/(?:#{s}+)([a-z])/){ $1.upcase }
    end

    case first_letter
    when :upper, true
      str = str.gsub(/(\A|\s)([a-z])/){ $1 + $2.upcase }
    when :lower, false
      str = str.gsub(/(\A|\s)([A-Z])/){ $1 + $2.downcase }
    end

    str
  end
end

=begin
  Jekyll filter to convert string to camelcase
  Usage:
    {% 'string' | camelcase %}
=end
module Jekyll
  module CamelCase
    def camelcase(input)
      input.camelize(:lower)
    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::CamelCase)
```

It is successful when filtering a string:

`{{ 'Page Title' | camelcase }} # pageTitle`

...but not when used on a page variable:

`{{ page.title | camelcase }} # Page Title`

Could there be something I am missing?
Could someone try this on there own Jekyll installation?

It's not super important, but it has been bugging me for hours.

Thanks everyone. =)

Comment: Here, both produce `"Page Title" => "page title"`. Jekyll 3.0.x, 3.1.x, ruby 2.1.8, 2.3.0

Comment: Does this mean that there's something wrong with the camelize function?

Comment: @DavidJacquel you were right. The regex `[a-z]` didn't match my string `Hello World` and only converted the first letters to lower case. Swapping both `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]` out with `[\w]` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with these three lines:

```
# mainly this one
str = str.gsub(/(?:#{s}+)([a-z])/){ $1.upcase }

# but also these two as well
str = str.gsub(/(\A|\s)([a-z])/){ $1 + $2.upcase }
str = str.gsub(/(\A|\s)([A-Z])/){ $1 + $2.downcase }
```

When I supplied the string `Hello World`, the regex didn't match the space as it is followed by a capital letter. E.g. `\s[a-z]` doesn't match `' W'`.
So "shorthand Word character" (`\w`) was used instead.

The code below works:

```
=begin
 # Custom to camelcase function
 # Usage:
 #   'string'.camelize
 #   'string'.camelize(:lower)
=end
class String
  def camelize(*separators)
    case separators.first
    when Symbol, TrueClass, FalseClass, NilClass
      first_letter = separators.shift
    end

    separators = ['_', '\s'] if separators.empty?

    str = self.dup

    separators.each do |s|
      str = str.gsub(/(?:#{s}+)([\w])/){ $1.upcase }
    end

    case first_letter
    when :upper, true
      str = str.gsub(/(\A|\s)([\w])/){ $1 + $2.upcase }
    when :lower, false
      str = str.gsub(/(\A|\s)([\w])/){ $1 + $2.downcase }
    end

    str
  end
end

puts('Hello World'.camelize())        # HelloWorld
puts('Hello World'.camelize(:lower))  # helloWorld
puts('Hello World'.camelize(:upper))  # HelloWorld
puts('hello world'.camelize())        # HelloWorld
puts('hello world'.camelize(:lower))  # helloWorld
puts('hello world'.camelize(:upper))  # HelloWorld
```